# Wikidata: an effective way to count items that share two properties

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I would like to count the number of Wikidata items that have two properties at the same time. For example, a Viaf ID and a BNF ID, or a LoC Id and a SUDOC id. The first way that comes to my mind would be a query like this:

```
SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT ?item) AS ?count) WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P214 ?viaf.
  ?item wdt:P268 ?bnf.
}
```

[Try it.](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%28COUNT%28DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%29%20AS%20%3Fcount%29%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP214%20%3Fviaf.%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP268%20%3Fbnf.%0A%7D)

But this query is inefficient (23 seconds) and, to apply it to 10 properties, would require 90 comparisons two by two. Is there a more efficient way to perform these calculations?

Comment: I have a feeling the better question is *why* you want to calculate all of these, especially on a recurring basis. My sense is that you've fallen prey to the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem#66378)...

Comment: @TallTed Sorry if my question seems opaque. I just want to know how many BNF IDs have a Viaf equivalent according to Wikidata. But I want to know that for many other properties than these two, that's why I'm looking for a more effective way than a lot of comparisons two by two.

Comment: This is already the most simple query to compute it, it's basically a join on two triple patterns. You could also rewrite it to `SELECT (COUNT(?item) AS ?count) WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P214 []
  filter exists{?item wdt:P268 []}
}` , but this might be even slower than using some join operation.

Comment: You can see all statistics as well as the query plan [here](https://query.wikidata.org/bigdata/namespace/wdq/sparql?explain&query=SELECT%20(COUNT(DISTINCT%20%3Fitem)%20AS%20%3Fcount)%20WHERE%20{%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP214%20%3Fviaf.%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP268%20%3Fbnf.%0A})

Comment: Try to add `hint:Query hint:maxParallel 200 .`  P.S. Not sure the query is executed  in the way you describe... What are your 10 properties?

Comment: @StanislavKralin what does this change for his query? It seems to work faster (~5s, though caching might also be matter since we run the same query several times right now)

Comment: @ASKW Thanx, It's a bit what I feared.

Comment: @StanislavKralin  I would actually like to compare over two hundred externalids...  And 40 000 queries is not a solution. I can always count the triples from a dump, but I feel that extracting only the externalids won't be so simple.

Comment: Well, at least you can use the optimizer hint from @StanislavKralin . But two hundred, and then pair wise? That's `n` chose `k`, i.e. `200 ` chose `2` (binominal coefficient), right? What is the use-case? You're looking for some kind of correlations in the dataset?

Comment: extraction from N-Triples would be simple in Linux bash. all the tools are there. whether it's faster, don't know

Comment: @ASKW Thanks for the advice. I'll try what exists, like [this](https://github.com/maxlath/wikidata-filter/blob/HEAD/docs/how_to.md), and if it doesn't work tinker with a tailor-made solution.

Comment: FYI, someone did this work and recently [put his database online](https://tools.dicare.org/properties/?property=214&type%5B%5D=ExternalId#jaccard_index)